# Compute Equal error rate from Similarity Matrix

Tags: matrix, similarity

I have a 1000x1000 similarity matrix?
How can I calculate FAR (false acceptance rate) 
and FRR (false rejection rate) from this matrix

Comment: what have you done so far, except asking this question?

Comment: if I know what is the meaning of values in the similarity matrix 
everything will be fine later